# why compiler complains use undeclared identifier 'f1'

Tags: c++, templates

```
int f() {
    return 1;
}

int g(int i) {
    return i;
}
template <typename F1, typename F2>
class Composer {
public:
    Composer(F1 *ff1, F2 *ff2): f1(ff1), f2(ff2) {}
    /*
    auto operator() () const -> 
    // if i insert this code, 
    // here compiler complains "use undeclared identifier 'f1'"
    decltype(f2(f1())) {
        return f2(f1());
    }
    */
    template<typename... Ps>
    auto operator() (Ps... ps) const -> decltype(f2(f1(ps...))) {
        return f2(f1(ps...));
    }
private:
    F1 *f1;
    F2 *f2;
};
int main() {
    Composer<decltype(f), decltype(g)> c(f, g);
    // compiler complains here "no matching function for call to 
    // object of type Composer<decltype(f), decltype(g)>"
    c();
}
```

i wanna know what's wrong with above code. why does compiler complains no match function for calling c()? why does compiler complains f1 undeclared if i insert the non-template function "operator() () const"? thanks for reading, i'm anxious to know the answer, please help me!

Comment: Hm, had to delete original comment. As it turns out, g++ accepts referring to *already declared* members. The out-commented code above refers forward to a later member declaration, that's definitely ungood. But I'm not quite sure what the standard says about it when the member declaration comes first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[basic.scope.class]/p1:

> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of
>   the declarative region following the name’s point of declaration, but
>   also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   *exception-specification*s, and *brace-or-equal-initializer*s of
>   non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

*trailing-return-type*s are not in the list. Therefore, the normal rules apply - `f1` and `f2` must be declared before they are used.

In C++14, you can return `decltype(auto)` and drop the trailing return type. Otherwise, you can move them up or use `declval`.

Comment: Excellent answer, +1.

Comment: hum, but i still wanna know the details of how to use decltype(auto) and declval to solve this problem, can you give a specific example?